# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: when i use res.write() along with res.send()

Tags: node.js, request

i am a beginner in node.js ..
**ques:** my code perfectly when i just use res.send() but as soon as i add res.write() above it it gives me this ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT...
`hey !! I am a beginner in Node.js

```
const express = require("express");

const https = require("https");
const app = express();


app.get("/",function(req,res)
{

   const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
   q=delhi,india&units=metric&appid=e36e62ed67d73dd0d9a98182ed7b763a"

https.get(url,function(response)
{
    response.on("data",function(data)
    {
        const weatherData= JSON.parse(data);
        // console.log(weatherData);
        const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
        const max_temp =weatherData.main.temp_max;
        const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
        console.log("temp :"+ temp);
        console.log("max:" +max_temp);
        console.log(icon);
        const imgurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png"

        res.write("<p> yeah !! i am sending back <p>");
        res.write("<img src="+imgurl+">");

        
        res.write("<h3>the MAX-Temprature in NEW DELHI ,INDIA is :" +max_temp+"degrees celcius 
         </h3>");
        res.write("<h1>The Temprature in NEW DELHI - INDIA is :"+ temp +"degrees celcius </h1>");
       
       res.send("bye");
        })

        })
        })

     app.listen(3000,function()
     {
        console.log("server is running at port 3000");
       })
```

Comment: You can't use `write` and then `send`. Either use `res.write(...); res.end();` or `res.send();` Both `write` and `send` send headers so you have to use one or the other. Also `res.send('hello');` is a shortcut for `res.write('hello'); res.end();`

Comment: @molda what if i want to send multiple response that could only be done by res.write()...so can i say this that res.send() can only be used to print 1 line result

Comment: No, you can send any number of lines with send. You just add lines to a string variable and then send the variable. In fact you are unlikely going to use res.write at all. Since you are using express.js you are going to use res.send, res.json or res.sendFile. res.write will only be useful in special cases. Also have a look at view engines https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines it makes it easier to build a html.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `res.write()` and `res.send()` together.  You either use `res.send()` by itself or if you want to use `res.write()`, then you use `res.end()` to finish the response.

So, you either send a response like this:

```
res.send(...)
```

or like this:

```
res.write(...);
res.write(...);
res.end(...);
```

Comment: its really not a compulsion to use res.send() to end up??

Comment: @PallaviVohra = Huhh?  You just don't use `res.send()` and `res.write()` together.  I don't think I can make my answer any more clear.  If you still don't understand, please clarify what exactly you don't understand.