# Node.js : res.write set headers and it should not

Tags: node.js, express

I totally understand that I can't write HTTP headers 2 times. But

This code works :

```
app.use(function(err , req , res , next) { 

    // res.write("message");
    res.send("erreur 500");

});
```

But with this code :

```
app.use(function(err , req , res , next) { 

    res.write("message");
    res.send("erreur 500");

});
```

I got : `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

But I read that res.write doesn't set headers. So I don't understand why I. can't use write before send. Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: From the express docs, you can see a snippet on default error middleware and how it checks whether headers have been already sent using `res.headersSent`. You should add this check as well and that should take care of the error for you. Link to docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Headers must be sent before the actual contents are sent. 
So, for `write` to send something immediately, if the headers had not been sent yet, it must send some headers before it can do its job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERR\_HTTP\_HEADERS\_SENT: when i use res.write() along with res.send()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870447/err-http-headers-sent-when-i-use-res-write-along-with-res-send)

Answer (score 0):

As some peoples wrote in comments, this question has already been answered here :

[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: when i use res.write() along with res.send()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870447/err-http-headers-sent-when-i-use-res-write-along-with-res-send)